# Converting a dynamic 4-digit year to a 2 digit year using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to convert a dynamically generated date from something like 20-Apr-2013 to 20.04.13. So far I managed to convert the month and change the spacers. But converting the year still escapes me. here is what I came up with so far. How to move forward?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


                $('.date').each( function() {


    var oldDate = $(this).text();

    var month;

    if( oldDate.indexOf('-') > 0 ){

        var dateSplit = oldDate.split('-');

        var year = dateSplit[2];

        if( year.length == 2){
            year = year;
        }

        switch(dateSplit[1])
        {
            case 'Jan': month = "01";
            break;
            case 'Feb': month = "02";
            break;
            case 'Mar': month = "03";
            break;
            case 'Apr': month = "04";
            break;
            case 'May': month = "05";
            break;
            case 'Jun': month = "06";
            break;
            case 'Jul': month = "07";
            break;
            case 'Aug': month = "08";
            break;
            case 'Sep': month = "09";
            break;
            case 'Oct': month = "10";
            break;
            case 'Nov': month = "11";
            break;
            case 'Dec': month = "12";
            break;
        }

        $(this).text(dateSplit[0] + '.' + month  + '.' + year);
    }
    else if( oldDate.indexOf(('/') > 0 ) ){

        var dateSplit = oldDate.split('/');

        var year = dateSplit[2];

        if( year.length == 2){
            year = year;
        }

    }


    });

  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple arithmetic:

```
year = year % 100;
```

But why do you want to do this? Don't you remember the Y2K problem?

Comment: you know very well that programmers rarely get to control things like date format.

Comment: client requirement. Some friend of his told him it the page will load faster without the 20. No amount of talk worked in explaining that running js to change the format of a renderer-dynamic date will slow it down more.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) it is meant to solve this exact problem.  Even if you don't use it, the [source code](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) may provide some pointers.

Can you convert oldDate to a Date object and go from there?

```
var newDate = new Date(oldDate);
var month = newDate.getMonth();
var year = newDate.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2); //get the last 2 digits of the full year
```

Here is a reference of the [functions on a javascript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods)

Answer (score 2):

```
"20-Apr-2013".replace(/(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)/,function(p,p1,p2,p3) {
  return p1+'.'+String("00"+('janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec'.indexOf(p2.toLowerCase())/3+1)).slice(-2)+'.'+p3.slice(-2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better converting it to a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) first:

```
$('.date').each(function() {

    var d = new Date($(this).text());

    $(this).text(d.getDate() + '.' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '.'
                    + ('' + d.getFullYear()).substr(2, 2));

});
```